# French Schengen Issued visa but more consecutive days staying in Italy

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, france, italy, multiple-entry

I have a Schengen visa issued by France, now I am traveling to France From July 21-24 (3 nights) and Sept 16-19 (3 nights), but I am going to Italy as well on Aug 25-29. Obviously I have more consecutive nights of stay in Italy but I am visiting France twice. Would that be a problem with the borders?

Comment: It's unlikely to matter that much in practice but where are you going in-between? Touring various country in the Schengen area? Or going back home? Also, is France the first country you are visiting in the Schengen area?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I won’t be going in between countries (i.e france-italy consecutively), just separately, france for a few days and italy as mentioned. Also france is my point of entry.

Comment: What I was trying to ask is what you will do during the gap? You have to be somewhere in the world between July 24 and Aug 25, is it in the Schengen area? Is it one or several trips to the Schengen area? The whole “main destination” rule is for a single trip.

Comment: July 24 and aug 25 I will be in France.

Comment: And **in between**?? Where are you July 25th for example?

Answer (score 3):

What’s important is usually what you do on your first stay. In this case it’s all in France so the next stays in Italy or France don’t matter.

What does matter is that you have a multiple-entry visa, and that it’s valid all along, though.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Schengen visa has to applied from the country which is your main destination, and for tourist visas, it is the country where you spend the most nights. And you are spending most nights in France. Consecutive or not, is irrelevant.

Also, once you have got the visa, generally, even if you spend more days in Italy, or visit other countries, you should be fine. There is nothing wrong in changing plans after you get the visa. What matters is intent. Genuine changes are fine.

You are ok anyway as you are spending the most days in France.

Comment: Thank you, I think I was over analyzing what the rules has said that I should have more nights on the main country of destination and worried that I only have 3 nights stay in each trip to france and Italy was 4 nights

Comment: The number of nights only determines the main destination if there is no clear, better determination. For instance, visiting a family wedding for three nights followed by five nights at the beach could still make the shorter part the main destination.

Comment: I know, that's why I mentioned the term "main destination", and then mentioned that "for tourist visas, it is the country where you spend the most nights". Even though officially, they are all type-c short stay visas, some countries ask you to specify whether it is for "tourism" or visiting family/friends or a business engagement or attending a short study program etc. For tourism, maximum nights determine the main destination.